# (Intuition) how big is the church-kleene ordinal?

Tags: intuition, ordinals

The church kleene ordinal is defined as the first ordinal that cannot be computed.

**But how should we imagine this ordinal? What is the "limit process" that leads to it?**

Comment: It's labeled $\omega_1^{CK}$ for a reason - it's the supremum of the set of all computably countable ordinals, in the same way that $\omega_1$ is the supremum of the set of ordinals. If you want to think of that as a limit process, then that seems like the most sensible answer to the question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Did you mean that  $\omega_1$ is the supremum of the set of **countable** ordinals?

Comment: @John: All ordinals are countable if you work inside $H(\omega_1)$... :P

Comment: Belatedly, but yes, I very much meant 'countable', and had countable in my thinking process all th way up to where I typed. D'oh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\omega_1^{CK}$ is also the first uncomputable ordinal. So if $f(n)$ is the largest ordinal defined by a length $n$ turingmachine. Then $\omega_1^{CK}$ is $$\lim_{n\to\omega} f(n)$$